# How to flush unified cache / Data Cache in ARM on the basis of VA

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

Found this MCR p15, 0, Rd, c7, c5, 1

But if I have a address VA - 0x40008000 how to set Rd ?

Comment: For the armv7a, this seems to be *Invalidate instruction caches by MVA to PoU*.  So this is an L1/L2-Icache invalidate.  Also, it seems that this `cp15` is optional to some *debug* variants.  It is possible that it may not be available for whatever *ARM* you are targeting.  Auselen is right that `Rd` is simply any ARM register; but my guess is you knew that?  Where are you reading about *c7, c5, 1*?  Provide a link if you can.

Comment: See: [Synchronous external abort...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627558/synchronous-external-abort-on-translation-table-walk/), which is apparently related?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
LDR R0, =0x40008000
MCR p15, 0, R0, c7, c5, 1
```